# Weaker version of a Dynkin-system?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

Let $M$ be a non-empty set. A Dynkin-system $\mathcal D$ on $M$ is a system of subsets of $M$ such that

1. $M\in \mathcal D$
2. $\mathcal D$ is closed with respect to proper differences
3. $\mathcal D$ is closed with respect to countable disjoint unions.

Is there a name for a system of subsets $\mathcal E$ of $M$ which satisfies axioms 2 and 3 and instead of axiom 1 it satisfies $\emptyset \in \mathcal E$?

Are there any special applications of such a system of sets?

Comment: I haven't ever encountered this before, but for example, given two measures $\mu,\nu$ on some common $\sigma$-algebra on $M$, the collection of sets $B$ with $\mu(B) = \nu(B)$ would be such a system.  (If they are probability measures then it is a Dynkin system.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting! I'm only able to show this if the measures are assumed to be finite, though. Does this also hold for measures that can take on infinite values?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, they should be finite measures.  Otherwise 2 can fail.  Example: $\mu$ is counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, $\nu = 2\mu$, $A = \{2,3,4,5,\dots\}$.  Then $\mu,\nu$ agree on $\mathbb{N}$ and on $A$ but not on $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$.